# Nom commun exprimant quelque chose de ludique

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Je cherche un nom commun qui pourrait être utilisé exactement de la même manière que *« difficulté »*, mais dans le sens *« ludique »* ou *« cool »*…
Le contexte, c'est l'écriture d'exercices à faire, dans un tableau Excel ©, et je cherche à mettre une note de *« difficulté »*, et une note de *« est-ce que c'est marrant à résoudre »*, mais je n'arrive pas à trouver de terme…

Par exemple :

> Exercice 1 | Difficulté: 1/5 | Fun: 4/5
>   Exercice 2 | Difficulté: 5/5 | Fun: 3/5

*Ludicité* ou *coolitude* me paraissent peu communs…
J'aimerais éviter les anglicismes (*fun* par exemple). Le langage ne doit pas être familier (usage professionnel).

Avez-vous des idées ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pourquoi pas l'un des mots suivants

> Amusement
>
> Divertissement
>
> Récréation

Comment: Divertissement est parfait ! Merci.